# Resharper formatting solution wide

Tags: resharper

Is there any way to run the resharper code cleanup for all the solution items?

The only possible way is on saving or on opened documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the solution in "Solution Explorer", select "Cleanup Code...".

Comment: Sometimes it's in front of you, but you can't see. Thank you.